# How to create a filter that does the SQL equivalent of WHERE ... IN for SQLite.Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I would like to filter results for the same column with multiple values

example in sql:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE status = 1 AND current_condition = ("New", "Working")
```

this will return all rows from `myTable` where the status is 1 and the current_condition is "New" OR "Working"

how do I do this in SQLite.swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raw SQL in Swift. So you can use the string you posted.

[Raw SQL](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#executing-arbitrary-sql)

[Using Filters](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#filter-operators-and-functions)

I use Filters, gives me more insight.

Comment: To clarify, you can use `["New", "Working"].contains(current_condition)`.